# Stretch background image to fit

Tags: reveal.js

I'm trying to get the background image in my reveal.js presentation to adjust its aspect ratio to fit the screen. Changing the size seems simple enough via

```
data-background-size=...
```

but I can't find anything that shows me how to make the image stretch to fit the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it manually entering two parameters: `data-background-size="800px 600px"` for example.

Answer (score 2):

This stretches the image to fit the slide, keeping its aspect ratio:

```
data-background-size="contain"
```

The attribute is mentioned in the [Backgrounds section](https://revealjs.com/backgrounds/) of the documentation.

For possible values of `data-background-size`, see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).